# Question regarding multiple singly linked lists

Tags: c

I'm trying to create multiple singly linked lists by using a list struct and a node struct. What I am thinking is each new list is told apart by a different head. But what makes me confused is how do I initialize a new head for each list and then add on nodes?

When I worked with just one list I was able to just allocate memory for the one head pointer and set it to NULL and then just add on new nodes.

My structs looks like this for reference:

```
typedef struct node
{
   int value;
   struct node *next;
}node_t;

typedef struct list
{
   struct list *head;
   int size;
}list_t;
```

If you feel like I've been unclear on something just ask and I will clarify!
Thanks

Comment: What did you try and how didn't it work?

Comment: _"When I worked with just one list I was able to just allocate memory for the one head pointer and set it to NULL and then just add on new nodes":_ you should show us at least show us _that_ code.

Comment: Sorry I was unclear in my question. What I meant by that sentence is that I have done that in another exercise where I didn't have the link_t struct so I only dealt with one list. I didn't show that because I didn't think it was very relevant to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your list structure `head` should actually be a `node_t` - first node in the list.
And then you will chain the nodes by assigning another `node_t` to `next`

```
typedef struct node
{
   int value;
   struct node *next;
}node_t;

typedef struct list
{
   node_t *head;
   int size;
}list_t;
```

Simple example for reference:

```
node_t node1;
node_t node2;

node1.value = 1;
node1.next = &node2;
node2.value = 1;
node2.next = NULL;

list_t list;
list.head = &node1;
list.size = 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

After re-reading your question multiple times, I probably finally understand what you are trying to achieve. You want `list_t` to contain multiple "lists" of type `node_t`.Then you need to make `head` an array of `node_t` pointers like this:

```
typedef struct node
{
   int value;
   struct node *next;
}node_t;

typedef struct list
{
   node_t *head[2];
   int size;
}list_t;
```

(i've used array of static size of 2 for simplicity. If you want to make it dynamic, you will need to take care of memory allocations on your own)

And example code:

```
// list1
node_t node11;
node_t node12;   
node11.value = 1;
node11.next = &node12;
node12.value = 1;
node12.next = NULL;

//list2
node_t node21;
node_t node22;
node11.value = 2;
node11.next = &node22;
node12.value = 2;
node12.next = NULL;

list_t list;
list.head[0] = &node11;
list.head[1] = &node21;
list.size = 2;
```

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for taking the time to answer my question! Sorry for not being very precise as I am new to this subject and programing as a whole. 

What I really meant now that I have read both your answers is that list_t is used to contain all the nodes in that list. As I understand it your first answer seems to be what I am looking for. 

For example, list1 has two nodes 2 and 1. The head is referring to the 2 which then becomes the head. node2.next = &node1 and node1.next = NULL. To create a second list I just do the same. list2. create two more nodes 3 and 4 .....

Comment: .....  where list.head = &node4 and node4.next =&node3 and node3.next = NULL.

and by now I should have two lists I think?

Comment: yes exactly what you said. My first answer is the common way how linked lists are usually  "teached". If it answers your question you can mark it as accepted answer.